# Object Keys de um JSON está salvando o ultimo valor

Tags: javascript, array

Gente quando eu executo o `Object Keys` ele captura toda Array do Objeto e atualiza os dados do `component` só que não todos e a saída só vem o ultimo valor da Array:

```js
var obj = {
  index: {
    path: "/",
    component: "./platform/system/index/index.vue",
    meta: {
      nav: "none"
    }
  },
  teste: {
    path: "/teste",
    component: "./platform/system/index/teste.vue",
    children: {
      userList: {
        path: "/users",
        component: "./platform/system/users/index.vue",
        lazy: "base"
      },
      testList: {
        path: "/system",
        component: "./platform/system/test/system.vue",
        lazy: "base"
      }
    }
  }
};

class Access {
  static getRaiz(obj) {
    var teste = {};

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(item) {
      var json = obj[item],
        directory = json.component;

      Object.assign(teste, json, {
        component: "() => import('" + directory + "')"
      });
    });
    return JSON.stringify(teste, null, '\t');
  }
}


document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + Access.getRaiz(obj) + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na forma como o [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) funciona. Este método substitui todas as propriedades no objeto que já existirem e adiciona todas as que não existem.

Veja um exemplo pequeno deste principio:

```js
let pessoa1 = { nome: "Marco", idade : 20};

//atribuir nome e altura a pessoa1
Object.assign(pessoa1, { nome: "Serafim", altura: 1.8});

console.log(pessoa1);
```

Repare como o `nome` foi substituído e a `altura` foi adicionada.

---

No seu código quando é executado o `assign`:

```
Object.assign(teste, json, {
    component: "() => import('" + directory + "')"
});
```

Irá substituir todas as propriedades existentes com o mesmo nome, especificamente `path` e `component`, e por isso apenas vê as da ultima propriedade, o `teste`.

Se o que pretende é criar um novo objeto com um `component` alterado, pode simplificar para algo como:

```
teste[item] = json;
teste[item].component = "() => import('" + directory + "')";
```

Exemplo:

```js
var obj = {
  index: {
    path: "/",
    component: "./platform/system/index/index.vue",
    meta: {
      nav: "none"
    }
  },
  teste: {
    path: "/teste",
    component: "./platform/system/index/teste.vue",
    children: {
      userList: {
        path: "/users",
        component: "./platform/system/users/index.vue",
        lazy: "base"
      },
      testList: {
        path: "/system",
        component: "./platform/system/test/system.vue",
        lazy: "base"
      }
    }
  }
};

class Access {
  static getRaiz(obj) {
    var teste = {};

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(item) {
      var json = obj[item],
        directory = json.component;
      
      teste[item] = json;
      teste[item].component = "() => import('" + directory + "')";

    });
    return JSON.stringify(teste, null, '\t');
  }
}


document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + Access.getRaiz(obj) + '</pre>';
```